# Managing JavaScript setIntervals in chrome [devtools]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, setinterval

I have a JavaScript application that utilizes `setInterval()` for a number of timed processes. I am looking for the best method of managing these timed processed from within Chrome Devtools. I know that code can be written to manage the processes from within the JS application itself, but I was wondering if there was a process already integrated into Devtools to review and manage these processes.

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no builtin feature for Chrome Devtools that displays `setInterval` or similar (like `setTimeout`)

Comment: What do you mean by "manage"? You can view intervals and timeouts getting called from, say, a flame chart (what shows when you do a Performance trace). But typically people mean more that view when they say "manage"...

Comment: ...to be able to view, create, start, pause, and stop intervals from within devtools, or a chrome extension that provides similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could open up the console and call the `setInterval()` from there.  You would be able to clear them from there as well.

Comment: I don't see any interface for clearing intervals in the Devtools console... I mean, you can type `clearInterval(id)` but that's just writing the code yourself.